# How to generate a PDF from a portion of a Wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

A client of mine has a food blog hosted on WordPress. Each post entry contains some text and a `div` called "recipes" with some more text inside it. They would like to add to this `div` a link that generates a PDF of the recipe, dynamically, for saving or printing, as the user sees fit.

I have seen quite a few Wordpress plugins that offer the conversion of *entire posts* to PDF but not anything that's customizable enough to select a given portion of a post, the way we'd like to.

Any suggestions on how to do this? I'm comfortable with PHP, Javascript, CSS but am new to the various PDF libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) It's pretty easy to work with :) This is from the documentation:

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

$html =
  '<html><body>'.
  '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
  'templating system.</p>'.
  '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this but I posted a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783241/how-to-create-a-link-that-supplies-info-to-a-php-library). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more control than [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) you could always use PHP's XML/XSL methods to convert the HTML to XSL:FO and use [FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) on the commandline to generate the PDF. It's a little long-winded but you get complete control of the output styling/structure, the ability to "lock" the PDF, provide metadata, etc.